# creating a simple TCP server in F# and Suave.IO

Tags: f#, suave

Is it possible, using Suave.IO and F#, to create a simple one-line TCP server along the lines of the http server below?

```
startWebServer defaultConfig (Successful.OK "Hello World!")
```

(the TCP server could do something simple like reply with the string it received)

Thanks, Ian

Comment: What have you tried. Show us your code and explain where you had a problem. Have you taken the [tour]? Have you read [ask]? Have you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) You run the risk of having this closed because you are expecting us to do work you should be doing.

Comment: One good place to always check for simple use cases for a library is in the test cases if they exist. Did you look for any test cases? Take a look at these [test](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/blob/master/src/Suave.Testing/Testing.fs).

Comment: Check out [Akka I/O](http://getakka.net/docs/IO) in Akka.NET

Comment: @Ringil, the main page of the Suave documentation states 'Still in its early stages Suave supports HTTPS, multiple TCP/IP bindings', though I've not been able to find examples using TCP in the documentation.

Comment: I guess this means listening on multiple TCP ports or interfaces, not protocols

Comment: @ArtemKoshelev, I was thinking of a server listening for client connections on a single server socket, connection requests would result in a new client-server connection being setup for the client, i.e basic client/server tcp stuff.

Comment: @ArtemKoshelev, I am interested in Suave.io specifically because I want to investigate how Suave uses SocketAsyncEventArgs (if it does at all)

Comment: Well you can find the uses of `SocketAsyncEventArgs` if you just search the Github repository: https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=SocketAsyncEventArgs+. Using this you can also see https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/blob/d5130c2b6488569b677a17845bf599f073a896e7/src/Suave/Tcp.fs has a `startTcpIpServerAsync`, which might be what you want...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. If you look at their [API Reference](https://suave.io/Suave.html), they support 2 protocols, HTTP and HTTPS:

```
type Protocol =
    | HTTP
    | HTTPS of obj
    member secure : bool
```